# What is the Current State of the Art in AJAX + Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js

I was quite surprised to read about RJS in Rails 3. Is this the way most rails sites work with AJAX?

And if I'm working with Backbone (and [this](http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/) is a good example), won't it have conflicts with ujs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rjs is easy to use but is not the proper way to deal with Ajax. Rails developers know that; all the more, RJS should be extracted to a gem. Yep, sever side js is not that scalable.

Backbone has been developed with Rails backend, and it's philosophy is a bit inspired from the framework. So you won't have any problems: it has been extensively tested.

Speaking about Backbone and Rails, I suggest you use the `backbone-rails` gem ([my fork](https://github.com/apneadiving/backbone-rails) handles better the `delete` method but hasn't been merged yet).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about "most", but for some things, it's way easier than the alternatives (storing stuff in DOM, etc.) Would it *conflict* with Backbone? Dunno, but if you're using Backbone, what would you be using RJS for (except for non-Backboney parts, if any)? If you're using Backbone wouldn't you just use the Rails JSON bits?

Comment: well, I don't know, I'm used to python. this 'seamless' js integration creeps me out :)

Comment: Lol... I think if you were Backboning (uh) that there's be no need for the RJS stuff; that's really for apps that have *some* JS interactivity, but not implemented in a full "client-side" framework. Like for highlighting an updated row given an ID, etc.--it's pretty slick for things like that.

Comment: I'm learning from Agile Web Development with Rails and they talk about scrip.aculo.us - I thought rails was done with that library?

Comment: Which version of the book? The latest covers jQuery; the new default.

Comment: (Wrong book. I think jQuery is only the default with 3.1, not sure about 3.0 'cuz I've always used jQuery anyway :)

Comment: funny how fast things change. I have the latest version of the book, from march 2011.

Comment: That's so last month. (But seriously, 3.1 changes a fair number of things. The underlying basics are largely the same, except for the JavaScript library, asset pipeline, and some less-important things.)